# Include header files in Catkin

Tags: ros, include, catkin, dependencies

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to include multiple header files with CATKIN. Therefore, I used include_directories in my CMakeList.txt as shown below:

include_directories(/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/navigation/move_base/include/)

include_directories(/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/navigation/nav_core/include/)

Now, both includes have additional dependencies and therefore require other directories to be included. Since there is quite a number of directories to include, I need to get away of doing this per hand.

**My question now:**
Is there a way to recursively search for other dependencies and automatically include them?
I appreciate every hint and thank everybody for helping me!

Yours, sincerely

Daniel

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66315/include-header-files-in-catkin/) by [dneuhold](https://answers.ros.org/users/5295/dneuhold/) on ROS Answers with karma: 205 on 2013-07-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A catkin package should not depend on rosbuild packages. This is not a supported use case.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2013-07-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-07-01**:
That is it should not depend on rosbuild packages. (non-catkin could include system type dependencies)

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-07-01**:
What @Dirk Thomas is saying is that as long as navigation is not a catkin package, then to depend on it you will need to use rosbuild. Navigation will be catkinized in Hydro.